# ASP.NET MVC Routes: How to name an action something completely different than in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-routes

This is a continuation of a couple of previous questions I've had. I have a controller called UserController that I'd like to handle actions on two types of objects: User and UserProfile. Among other actions, I'd like to define an Edit action for both of these objects, and within UserController. They'll need to be separate actions, and I don't mind calling them EditUser and EditProfile in the *controller*, but I'd prefer if the URL's looked like this:

```
http://www.example.com/User/Edit/{userID}
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/User/Profile/Edit/{userProfileID}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve these routes, given the restraint for the actions being in the same controller?

And for context, previous questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080224/asp-net-mvc-routes-how-to-define-custom-route) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080546/asp-net-mvc-routes-conflicting-action-names-with-custom-route)

Thanks.

Comment: @Matt maybe should also mention the previous question where we were discussing earlier. Gives people some more information

Comment: @Matt, you already found a good solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just an suggestion, but can't you do something like this to map the correct routes?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProfileRoute", // Route name
    "User/Edit/{userProfileID}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "User", action = "EditUser" } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "ProfileEditRouet", // Route name
    "User/Profile/Edit/{userProfileID}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "User", action = "Editprofile" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

EDIT:
Then in your controller create two seperate methods called EditUser(guid userId) and Editprofile(guid userId)

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like the following: (untested)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EditUser",
    "User/Edit/{userID}", 
    new { controller = "User", action = "EditUser" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "EditProfile",
    "User/Profile/Edit/{userProfileID}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "EditProfile" });
```

EDIT:

Using MvcContrib (available from http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) the syntax is slightly clearer:

```
(using MvcContrib.Routing;)

MvcRoute
    .MappUrl("User/Edit/{userID}")
    .WithDefaults(new { controller = "User", action = "EditUser" })
    .AddWithName("EditUser", routes);

MvcRoute
    .MappUrl("User/Profile/Edit/{userProfileID}")
    .WithDefaults(new { controller = "User", action = "EditProfile" })
    .AddWithName("EditProfile", routes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using MvcContrib.Routing;

public class UserController : Controller
{
    [UrlRoute(Path = "User/Edit/{userID}")]
    public ActionResult UserEdit(int userID)
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is MvcContrib.Routing included in MVC 1.0?

Comment: hmm not sure...I didn't get into mvc game until 2.0. maybe try this one http://itcloud.codeplex.com/