# Route a url with parameters to a .NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a small .NET web app in an aspx file that currently has a form on the page. It takes the information from that form and does some stuff to it using a method in a `<script>` tag in the same file. Now I need a way to create a url, let's call it `base_url.com/do_something/field1/field2/field3`, where `field1`, `field2`, and `field3` are the fields currently in the form, so that I can bypass the form all together and just run the app from a url. I am using IIS 7.0, this is **not** a project created in VS. Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you're issuing a `POST` to an `ASPX` page, that sure is going to redirect, the code might look **something** like this:

```
var path = string.Format("base_url.com/do_something/{0}/{2}/{3}",
    Request.Form["field1"], Request.Form["field2"], Request.Form["field3"]);
```

then after getting the right path, simply do this:

```
Response.Redirect(path);
```

Comment: But is the question asking how to make sure that gets to the right server method?  I thought this question was about URL Rewriting on the server.

Comment: this is helpful, but I also need to know what @wagregg is suggesting... I'm pretty new to .NET

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net MVC, you get URL Routing baked in.  If this is an MVC application, then you can declare your mapping in your Global.asax file.  See this answer: [ASP.NET MVC Routes: How to define custom route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080224/asp-net-mvc-routes-how-to-define-custom-route)

If you do not have an ASP.Net MVC application, then URL rewriting can be done directly in IIS.  http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

HTH

Comment: From what I've been reading about URL rewriting, it seems like all it does is converts a URL with a query string into a clean URL, but I still need to map the clean URL to some sort of action. Can this be done with a URL rewrite?

Comment: You can do anything you'd like.  You want to map a Clean Url to a url with a query string.  It works like that too.  People do that for SEO all the time.